# Display/LCD drivers

Tags: mobile-phones, drivers, lcd

Can anybody tell me about techniques for buffering used in display drivers specifically in LCD's in Mobile phones ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can promise you that it varies.  Modern hardware on mobile phones is quite capable, but its still not always utilised.

Many operating systems don't have buffering - the drawing code accesses the memory DMAed by the display directly, and puts effort into syncing with the vertical retrace.

Then some operating systems introduced software double buffering for flicker-free redraw.  The new scene is composed onto an off-screen buffer, and then the final result is blitted to the screen memory.  I've seen implementations of this strategy that didn't vsync, though!

Then things like Android are built around efficient buffering at the hardware level.  The android surface flinger does it all behind the scenes.

Comment: You are right!!...buffering mechanism may vary..If you have some sample implementation ( code or a small piece of explanation) you can put it here plz

Comment: This is hardware-specific, not generic code.  If you mean to implement it, you could hire someone with phone experience to do this for you.